# Как установить предпочитаемый размер для одних JPanel и относительный для других в GridBagLayouts?

Tags: java, swing

Есть код:

```
public class GBLWeightMyTest1 extends JFrame {
private JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[5][5];
private GridBagLayout layout;

public GBLWeightMyTest1() {
    super("GridBagLayout");

    layout = new GridBagLayout();

    final JPanel content = new JPanel(layout);

    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

    constraint.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraint.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    constraint.gridwidth = 1;
    constraint.gridheight = 1;
    constraint.ipadx = 1;
    constraint.ipady = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j ++) {
        constraint.gridy = j;
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            constraint.weighty = 5;
        } else {
            constraint.weighty = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            constraint.gridx = i;
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            if ((i % 2 == 0) && (j % 2 == 0)) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("wood_button.png"));
                panel.add(label);

                panel.setPreferredSize(label.getPreferredSize());
                panel.setMaximumSize(label.getPreferredSize());

                panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

                constraint.weightx = 5;
                layout.setConstraints(panel, constraint);
            } else {
                panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
                constraint.weightx = 1;
                layout.setConstraints(panel, constraint);
            }
            panels[j][i] = panel;
            content.add(panel);
        }
    }

    pack();

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    getContentPane().add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GBLWeightMyTest1().setVisible(true);
}}
```

После метода pack() хотелось бы получить что-то похожее на:

[image: Результат развернутый вручную]

То есть за размер окна по умолчанию при запуске нужно взять размер иконки + относительный размер ячеек между иконками. (Ячейки эти - важная часть, я буду потом с ними работать) А при растягивании окна должны растягиваться иконки (и соответственно ячейки между всё в том же процентном соотношении).
Чтобы было понятнее - в цифрах. Размер иконки 40px x 40px. Соответственно ширина окна =

```
40px + (40px / 5) + 40px + (40px / 5) + 40px.
```

Такая же высота.

При растягивании, к примеру,

```
50px + (50px / 5) + 50px + (50px / 5) + 50px.
```

И второй вопрос. Не могу понять с чем связанно, но без GridBagLayout'а иконка так себя не ведет. А именно: не появляются лишние отступы между JLabel и JPanel (на изображении выше они белые). Как их убрать?

По идее у панельки в которой label с иконкой FlowLayout, и на него внешний менеджер влиять не должен...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Про размер окна**

Сейчас метод `pack()` вызывается до `getContentPane().add(content)`, то есть когда окно всё ещё пустое, поэтому оно получается нулевого размера. Панель `content` добавляется потом, окно остаётся нулевым. Нужно поменять местами эти две строки, и всё станет хорошо.

При этом надо иметь в виду, что `panel.setPreferredSize(label.getPreferredSize())` не совсем правильно, потому что фактически панель должна быть чуть-чуть больше за счёт рамки.

**Про белые отступы**

Похоже, это свойство `FlowLayout`: он располагает элементы по строчкам, и над первой строчкой сразу даёт отступ размера `vgap`. Можно задать `FlowLayout` с нулевыми отступами, но он всё равно не годится, потому что он не растягивает содержимое. Рекомендую использовать `BorderLayout`:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

**Про растягивание картинок**

А вот тут [всё сложнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size). `JLabel` не умеет автоматически растягивать картинки. Придётся либо при изменении размера окна генерировать новую картинку, либо использовать вместо `JLabel` самодельный компонент, который будет отображать картинку нужного размера:

```
private class StretchLabel extends JComponent {
    private Image image;
    public StretchLabel(ImageIcon icon){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight()));
        image=icon.getImage();
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Про пропорциональное изменение размеров:**

Чтобы изменять размер панели с сохранением пропорций, философски правильно написать свой `LayoutManager`, но проще добавить `ComponentListener`:

```
public class GBLWeightMyTest1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[5][5];
    private GridBagLayout layout;
    private JPanel content;
    int w0, h0;

    public GBLWeightMyTest1() {

        ...

        content = new JPanel(layout);

        ...

        getContentPane().add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        w0=getContentPane().getWidth();
        h0=getContentPane().getHeight();

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        getContentPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
                int w = getContentPane().getWidth();
                int h = getContentPane().getHeight();
                if( w*h0 < h*w0 ){
                    content.setBounds(0, 0, w, h0*w/w0);
                }else{
                    content.setBounds(0, 0, w0*h/h0, h);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Спасибо! 2 дня уже воюю... И как я про pack() сам не догадался?.. После исправлений возникли ещё 2 вопроса. Во-первых, почему-то перестали корректно отображаться ячейки с серым фоном, после pack() они становятся размером 1-2 пикселя. А во-вторых, как сделать так, чтобы при растягивании главная панель сохраняла свои пропорции. Тоже через метод paintComponent(Graphics g), только для главной панели?

Comment: @Yukon, серые ячейки становятся маленькими, если им тоже задать `BorderLayout`. Если задавать только ячейкам с картинками, то становится лучше (хотя тогда серые при уменьшении становятся слишком большими). Вообще `GridBagLayout` при наличии `preferredSize` иногда начинает вести себя странно, не всегда соответствует весам. Возможно, будет проще двигать все панели своими силами. Насчёт пропорций: я добавил новый код в ответ.

Comment: @Yukon добавлю ко всему, используйте `pack()`  в самом конце, для более положительного результата.

Comment: @Goblin Alchemist, а почему `GridBagLayout` вообще как-то реагирует на то, какой менеджер у встроенной в него панели? Ему же дан конкретный `weightx` и `weighty`?

Comment: @Yukon, думаю, потому что в зависимости от этого панель возвращает разные `preferredSize` и `minimumSize`